# How to check if payment sheet is open?

Tags: stripe-payments

I'm using React and I have an effect (i.e. `useEffect`) that tries to update the total in a `paymentRequest` (i.e. `paymentRequest.update`).

When I try to do that, stripe throws an error:

```
IntegrationError: You cannot update Payment Request options while the payment sheet is showing
```

…which make enough sense but now my issue is that I don't know how to check if the payment sheet is already open or not to prevent the update from being called.

---

I'm looking to do something like this:

```js
if (!paymentSheetOpen()) {
  paymentRequest.update({/* ... */});
}
```

How do I implement `paymentSheetOpen`?

Answer (score 1):

I asked this question on the stripe IRC and this was the user `timebox`'s answer:

> You need to listen to/for the `click` and `cancel` events, per here: https://stripe.com/docs/js/payment_request/update